# DataTables 1.9.4 get live row data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a legacy DataTable that has a range of hidden columns that the user can show, then edit the cell via editable, then hide again.

each cell has a hidden text input which editable populates when the value changes. I have foudn that in datatables 1.9.4 i can

```
var r = oTable.$('tr');
//loop through datatables rows
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
 //get current rows data
 var c = r[i];
 if (i === 0) {
   //convert to jQuery object
   jc = jQ(c);
   var changed = jc.find('.rowChanged').val();
 }
}
```

which gets me the current live data but only for columns that are showing.

I tried `oTable.fnGetData(c)` passing the current row but this give me the initial starting html for each cell and not the live html (some inputs may have changed)

is there a way to return a jQuery object similar to the `oTable.$()` api call that contains the entire rows live data and not just the visible rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by showing all columns, grabbing the data using the `oTable.$('tr')` and then hide the relevant columns again.